# How to affect the syntax highliting filetype from local vimrc?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am editing a source code in *language1*.

It doesn't have a built-in syntax highliting configuration into my vim.

However, its syntax is very similar to *language2*, which has. I think, syntax highliting the sources as *language2* would be pretty okay for me. Thus, I tried to set up the syntax highliting of *language2* to the files with extensions of *language1*.

Checking the syntax highliting configuration of my distribution-provided vim (`filetype.vim`), I found the line

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.<ext2>  setf language2
```

Thus, I inserted a line

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.<ext1>  setf language2
```

into my local `.vimrc`.

However, nothing happened. My source files - in *language1* - are still un-syntax highlited.

Why is it so? How could I make it working?

Comment: In my specific case: I am trying to syntax hightlig Typescript files (`.ts`) as if they would be Javascript, on a vim provided by debian/ubuntu. This is why I am trying to avoid to overwrite the distro-provided `/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim`. However, I tried to make the question as general as possible (I think not the question and also not the answer won't be specific to my environment).

Comment: If I overwrite `/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim`, then it works, but I am trying to use a local config, as overwriting distro-provided file is a bad thing on debian.

Comment: Does `set filetype=language2` work (i.e., not using `setf`)?

Comment: @Mass Wow! Yes, it works. But why the `au` command didn't work in my local vimrc?

Comment: Did you try `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.<ext1>  set filetype=language2` in your vimrc already?  The reason `set filetype` works and `setf` doesn't is because vim already knows `.ts` as having filetype=xml.  `setf` will not change the filetype if it's already set (I will add an answer if the code works in your vimrc).

Comment: @Mass Thank you very much! It solved the problem. It is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution is to just replace `setf` with `set filetype` in the line in your vimrc:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.<ext1>  set filetype=language2
```

This is explained in `:help ftdetect` but it is quite difficult understand.  In this specific case the reason is very simple- that vim has already used `setf` to set a file type for `ext1`.

Suppose `ext1=ts`.  In `/usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim`, we see,

```
" Qt Linguist translation source and Qt User Interface Files are XML
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ts,*.ui         setf xml
```

This means any following `setf` issued in `autocmd`s will fail:

```
:setf[iletype] [FALLBACK] {filetype}            *:setf* *:setfiletype*
        Set the 'filetype' option to {filetype}, but only if
        not done yet in a sequence of (nested) autocommands.
```